# Real Analysis: Showing $f: \Bbb Q \to \Bbb Q$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The following is all working in $\mathbb{Q}$, not $\mathbb{R}$. I am working with the function $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ defined piece-wise by

$f(x)=-1$ if $x^2<2$

$f(x)=1$ if otherwise

I hope to prove $f$ is continuous. The hint in my textbook suggests to break this down into two steps: One, show $f$ is continuous at $x$ if $x^2<2$ then, two, show $f$ is continuous at $x$ if $x^2>2$.

To prove the former, the books suggests we show: If $x^2<2$ and $\delta=\frac{2-x^2}{6}$, show that $y^2<2$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$. This is where I am stuck; I've hopelessly tried to prove this statement several ways to no avail.

I don't believe showing $|x-y|<\delta$ $\implies$ $y^2<2$ is possible solely through algebra as I've tried many different manipulations/factoring(s) and cannot seem to get it. Furthermore, I've thought of taking the limit of both sides (since $y<\frac{2-x^2}{6}+x$ can easily be obtained through algebra and the RHS $\to$ $\sqrt{2}$ as $x \to \sqrt{2}$) yet I know the limit need not preserve strict inequalities and, also, I am unsure if I can work with $\sqrt{2}$ like that because, technically, the entire problem is in $\mathbb{Q}$. I feel as if I am making this problem more difficult than it is. Any hints or solutions would be greatly appreciated; the problem has been eating at me all day and I'm now very curious of the solution after my many failed attempts.

Comment: Note that you can deal with the lack of preserving strict inequalities: if $x+\epsilon \leq \sqrt{2}$ and $y < x + \epsilon$, then $y < \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I believe many solutions were misled due to a mistake on my part. I defined $\epsilon=\frac{2-x^2}{6}$ when, in fact, I meant to define $\delta=\frac{2-x^2}{6}$. To be explicit, the problem is: Show $|x-y|<\delta$ $\implies$ $y^2<2$ if $x^2<2$ and $\delta=\frac{2-x^2}{6}$.

Comment: @Ryan I updated my answer based on your request to understand the strange condition from the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you take a sequence of rational numbers converging to some $x\in\mathbb{Q}$. Either $|x|<\sqrt{2}$ or $|x|>\sqrt{2}$; equality can never hold.

Then there is an interval $\{y\in\mathbb{R}: |x-y|<\delta\}$ and all such $y$ also satisfy $|y|<\sqrt{2}$ or $|y|>\sqrt{2}$. Either way the sequence is eventually constant after applying $f$, hence $f$ is continuous.

In particular if you write $|x-\sqrt{2}|=d$ then choosing $\delta =\min\{d/2,\epsilon/2\}$, you can assure the $y$ satisfy the condition claimed.

For the original claim--as per the op's request:

$$2-x^2=|\sqrt 2-x||\sqrt 2+x|$$

$$<d|\sqrt 2+x|$$

then since $|x|<\sqrt 2$ we can apply the triangle inequality and get:
$$2-x^2< d(\sqrt 2 +|x|)$$

$$\le d(\sqrt2+\sqrt 2)=2d\sqrt 2$$

then dividing by 6 we get:

$${2-x^2\over 6}< {d\sqrt 2\over 3}<d$$

So this means $|x-y|<\delta<d$ hence $|y|<\sqrt 2$ by the definition of the number $d$.

Comment: Good solutions both you and Ian had. +1 to both of you. You had the way I'd do it. By the way-I think this exanple is due to Tom Korner-it appears as an exercise in the first edition of R.P. Burns' excellent NUMBERS AND FUNCTIONS:STEPS IN ANALYSIS and is mentioned in the preface. It's a really good problem for a student learning careful calculus to chew on.

Comment: Certainly. If we fix an $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, let $\epsilon>0$, and set $|x-\sqrt{2}|=d$, then choosing $\delta=\frac{d}{2}$ ensures $|x-y|<\delta$ $\implies$ $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, $\forall$ $y$. Just out of curiosity, though, I was hoping to prove the implication as I have now explained more clearly in my comment. Your proof certainly shows $f$ is continuous (probably in a better way than the books suggests) yet I'd like to understand specifically how to prove this implication due to my several attempts at not being able.

Comment: All I hope to show is: $|x-y|<\delta$ $\implies$ $y^2<2$ if $x^2<2$ and $\delta=\frac{2-x^2}{6}$. This is entirely my fault for being ambiguous about this in my original post (and my comment above of the $\epsilon$ \ $\delta$ confusion to my original post). I do not need clarification on your post and think it is a solid proof of $f$ being continuous yet it is not exactly what I was looking for (again, due to my ambiguity, no fault of your own).

Comment: @Ryan try this:  $2-x^2=|\sqrt 2-x||\sqrt 2+x|<d|\sqrt 2+x|$ then since $|x|<\sqrt 2$ this whole thing is less than $d(\sqrt 2 +|x|)\le d(\sqrt2+\sqrt 2)=2d\sqrt 2$, but then dividing by 6 we get:

$${2-x^2\over 6}\le {d\sqrt 2\over 3}<d$$

So this means $|x-y|<d\implies |y|<\sqrt 2$ which is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Your $f$ is locally constant, so it had better be continuous. But for a complete formal proof, just use this characterization of continuity: $f$ is continuous if and only if for every open $U$ in the target space (codomain), $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in the domain.
Well: if $U$ contains both $1$ and $-1$, then the inverse image is $\mathbb Q$, open. If it contains neither, inverse image is empty, also open. If $U$ contains $1$ but not $-1$, then the inverse image is $[\langle-\infty,\sqrt2\rangle\cup\langle\sqrt2,\infty\rangle]\cap\mathbb Q$, which, being the intersection of $\mathbb Q$ with an open of $\mathbb R$, is open in $\mathbb Q$. Similar if the inverse image contains $-1$ but not $1$, but shorter.

Comment: This is an excellent answer to my ultimate goal to prove $f$ is continuous; however, I only hope to show $|x-y|<\delta$ $\implies$ $y^2<2$ if $x^2<2$ and $\delta=\frac{2-x^2}{6}$. Furthermore, if $U$, as you've defined it, contains $1$ but not $-1$, is not the inverse image just $(\sqrt{2},\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}$? This is open as well so it does not change your result but I'm wondering whether or not I am correct

Comment: Are the order topology of $\mathbb{Q}$ and the topology that $\mathbb{Q}$ inherits from $\mathbb{R}$ the same?

Comment: Answering my own question: yes, they are, though this fact is not entirely trivial.

Comment: For the case that $U$ contains $1$ but not $-1$, isn’t $-2$ in $f^{-1}(U)$?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it, given some knowledge about real numbers. Find a sequence of rationals $x_n$ with $x_n^2 < 2$ and $x_n \to \sqrt{2}$. Given an $x$ with $x^2 < 2$ and $x>0$, find an $n$ with $x_n > x$. Then set $\delta=|x_n-x|$. Do the same for $x^2>2$ (and for $x<0$).

To follow your hint (which is completely agnostic about the existence of real numbers), note that for $x>0$, $f(x)=x^2$ is increasing, and for $x<0$, $f(x)=x^2$ is decreasing. So the "worst case" in an interval $[x-\delta,x+\delta]$ is $x+\delta$ for $x>0$ and $x-\delta$ for $x<0$.

So you can split into cases. That is, show that if $x>0$ and $x^2<2$ then $\left ( x+\frac{2-x^2}{6} \right )^2 < 2$, and that if $x<0$ and $x^2<2$ then $\left ( x - \frac{2-x^2}{6} \right )^2 < 2$.

Edit: actually, here's an intuitive but still completely rigorous proof. Let $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x^2 < 2$. Suppose $x_n$ is a sequence of rationals with $x_n \to x$. Because $x_n \to x$, there is an $N$ so that for $n \geq N$, $x_n^2 < 2$. (Sketch: $x_n^2 = (x_n-x+x)^2 = (x_n-x)^2 + 2x(x_n-x) + x^2$. Choose $N$ large enough that the first two terms are less than $|2-x^2|$.)

Then $x^2 \leq 2$ by preservation of nonstrict inequalities. But $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, so $x^2 \neq 2$, so $x^2 < 2$. Thus $f(x_n) \to f(x)$, so $f$ is continuous at $x$ Repeat for $x^2 > 2$.

Comment: +1 REALLY important to notice in this problem that the inequality is strictly less then the square root of 2. The problem doesn't make sense otherwise and that might be lost on a beginner.

Comment: I find your choice of $\delta$ in the first paragraph quite clever; thank you for that insightful example. Given $\epsilon>0$, your choice of $\delta$ shows $|x-y|<\delta$ $\implies$ $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. If we do the same for $x^2>2$ this proves the continuity of $f$. Also, I have a question about your edit. I understand your first paragraph to allow the sequence of rational to be such that $x_n^2<2$ no longer need hold like your first example. Given $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x^2<2$, I agree $\exists$ $N$ such that $n \geq N$ $\implies$ $x_n^2<2$.

Comment: (Continued). Then, you take the limit as $n \to \infty$ of both sides of the strict equality to get $x^2 \leq 2$. Since $x^2 \neq 2$, we conclude $x^2 < 2$. Yet, isn't this trivial because in your first sentence you say "let $x^2 < 2$"?

Comment: You're right, that part was redundant. All you need is that any sequence of rationals with $x_n \to x$ satisfies $x_n^2 < 2$ (if $x^2 < 2$) or $x_n^2 > 2$ (if $x^2 > 2$) for all $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 1):

$x + \epsilon$ is easier to work with than $x + \frac{2-x^2}{6}$.

Also, showing that $2 - (x+\epsilon)^2 \geq 0$ is easier than showing $(x+\epsilon)^2 \leq 2$.

But I do question the choice of $\epsilon$: I suspect Newton's method will give up a better choice of $\epsilon$. If we use Newton's method to approximate a root of the function $f(t) = t^2 - 2$, then given an approximation $x$ the next approximation is

$$ y = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = x - \frac{x^2 - 2}{2x} $$

and as I recall, Newton's method for estimating a square root always gives underestimates. (If I'm remembering that wrongly, then what is correct is that it alternates overestimates and underestimates, and thus just run the algorithm twice) I've done this sort of exercise before, and $2-y^2$ just magically simplifies: specifically to $(2-x^2)^2$, if I remember correctly.

And so it's probably better to have chosen

$$ \frac{2-x^2}{2x} $$

so long as $x$ isn't too far away from $\sqrt{2}$. But now I see the motivation behind their choice of $\epsilon$. If we have

$$ 0 < x < 3$$

then we have

$$ \epsilon < \frac{2-x^2}{2x} $$

and presumably, the choice of $\epsilon$ also winds up working out for the case of $x \leq 0$ as well.

However, I find that this "simplification" really just makes the problem more complicated, and it's much better to simply split the domain into cases and use different choices of $\epsilon$ on each.

Comment: I agree it makes the problem a bit more cumbersome,but I gotta give you +1 for creativity,Hurkyl!!!